# Generalize code to capture and crop a photo

Tags: codenameone

*This questions refers to Codename One only.*

Thanks to the commit [98dcbaa](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/98dcbaa2f1f740c102d63f772f422ecd4716546e) and re-working the test case [ImageViewerSample2778](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/98dcbaa2f1f740c102d63f772f422ecd4716546e/Samples/samples/ImageViewerSample2778/ImageViewerSample2778.java), I created a full working example to capture a photo and to crop it. My initial result is satisfying, at least in the Simulator:

[image]

It seems ok, however I wasn't able to write a code that is enough generic. The problem is the var `width`, used more times in the following code (it's used in the override of `calcPreferredSize` of `ImageViewer`, in `roundMask`, `maskImg` and `.fillArc`).

Maybe could my code be more generic using a custom layout? The problem of a fixed `width` is that the UI is not adapted if the Form is resized. Moreover a more generic code could be encapsulated in a method to capture, show and crop a photo.

Do you have any idea or suggestion to improve my code?

Java:

```
Form hi = new Form("Crop your avatar", new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_TOTAL_BELOW));
        hi.getContentPane().setUIID("Crop-Avatar-ContentPane");

        int width = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() - hi.getContentPane().getStyle().getMarginLeftNoRTL() - hi.getContentPane().getStyle().getMarginRightNoRTL();
        Image roundMask = Image.createImage(width, width, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        Graphics gr = roundMask.getGraphics();
        gr.setColor(0x000000);
        gr.fillArc(0, 0, width, width, 0, 360);
        Object mask = roundMask.createMask();
        Image maskImg = Image.createImage(width, width, 0xFFFFFFFF).applyMask(mask);
        maskImg = maskImg.modifyAlpha((byte) 200);
        Label maskLbl = new Label(maskImg, "Crop-Avatar-LabelMask");


        Container imageCropper = new Container(new LayeredLayout(), "NoMarginNoPadding");
        ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer() {
            @Override
            public Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(width, width);
            }
        };
        Container cnt1 = FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(viewer);
        viewer.setUIID("NoMarginNoPadding");
        cnt1.setUIID("NoMarginNoPadding");
        Container cnt2 = FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(maskLbl);
        cnt2.setUIID("NoMarginNoPadding");
        imageCropper.add(cnt1);
        imageCropper.add(cnt2);

        Button getCroppedImageFullSize = new Button("Confirm");
        getCroppedImageFullSize.addActionListener(e -> {
            ScaleImageLabel l = new ScaleImageLabel(viewer.getCroppedImage(0x0));
            Dialog.show("Crop is", l, new Command("OK"));
        });


        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, imageCropper);
        hi.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new SpanLabel("Move and zoom your photo to crop it as you want", "Crop-Avatar-Description"));
        hi.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, FlowLayout.encloseCenter(getCroppedImageFullSize));
        hi.show();

        Capture.capturePhoto(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (evt == null || evt.getSource() == null) {
                    // the user cancelled the image capturing
                    return;
                }
                String file = (String) evt.getSource();
                try {
                    Image img = Image.createImage(file);
                    viewer.setImage(img);
                    if (img.getWidth() != img.getHeight()) {
                        // we need to zoom to perfectly fit a square
                        viewer.setZoom(Math.max((float) img.getHeight() / img.getWidth(), (float) img.getWidth() / img.getHeight()) + 0.01f);
                    }                    
                    hi.revalidateWithAnimationSafety();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.p("Error loading captured image from camera", Log.ERROR);
                    Log.e(ex);
                }
            }
        });
```

CSS:

```
NoMarginNoPadding {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

Crop-Avatar-LabelMask {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1mm blue solid;
}

Crop-Avatar-Description {
    padding: 3mm;
    text-align: center;
}

Crop-Avatar-ContentPane {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 3mm;
    margin-right: 3mm;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to set the preferred size? Why not let the image viewer grow and fill up the space since you already have the mask. You might be able to do it efficiently with a painter and a general path to draw the shape instead of an image. I'll need to experiment a bit with this as I'd like to have a generic sample of this use case for the blog and the class docs.

Comment: I overrided the calcPreferredSize of ImageViewer because I don't know how to do a mask that automatically adapts itself to any size and any ratio, with a circle in the center. Moreover, the cropping provided by ImageViewer has the same x/y ratio of the shown Image, that why I set a preferred size and a zoom to make the photo to fit a square. This morning I tried to use a painter and a general path as you suggested, with the purpose to make a more generic and efficient code, but I wasn't able: I'm still not quite familiar with the use of the low-level drawing APIs. I'll wait for your tutorial.